# Twitter Bootstrap $().dropdown('toggle') keydown event not firing

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, onkeydown

I have a Twitter Bootstrap dropdown menu on a nav-bar which opens correctly when I click on it and the cursor up/down keys work correctly.

However if I open the same menu using:
`$('#menu').dropdown('toggle');` in a keydown or keyup event handler, the menu opens/closing correctly however the cursor up/down keys don't work. In fact the dropdown menu `keydown` event doesn't trigger.

Here is the html and Javascript:

```
<ul class="nav">   <!-- "KB Menu"   -->
    <li class="dropdown kb_menu hideit">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Knowledge Bases<b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" id="kb_menu">
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


$(document).on('keydown', function( event ){
    if ( event.ctrlKey ){
        if ( event.keyCode == 191 ){   // Ctrl+/ = 191
            $('#kb_menu').dropdown('toggle');
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried everything I can think off to no avail so far.

Comment: Will you please post the code you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line after `$('#kb_menu').dropdown('toggle')`:

```
$('#kb_menu').find('li:first > a').focus();
```

Comment: Fantastic, that resolves this issue. I had tried ```$('#kb_menu').focus()``` to no avail. The TBS toggle function also calls focus() but clearly the mouse click came into play. It seems like dropdown.toggle() should  do ```$('#kb_menu').find('li:first > a').focus();```  There is also a slight difference in behaviour as this selects the first menu item, whereas click doesn't. Anyway many thanks.

Comment: Adding the class `open` does the trick as well. In your case `$("#kb_menu").addClass("open")`